Water-level detection with bare metal probes in salt water?
Project
Hello - I am building a DIY automatic water changing system for my saltwater reef aquarium and I am looking for some ideas and feedback on a water detection circuit with bare metal probes (wire pairs really). I am controlling several peristaltic pumps with a web app running on a Raspberry Pi with calibration, timers, etc. I'll spare the details (happy to share more if interested), but I've ran tubes from my mixing station and drain in the garage to the tank and all is working well so far. I've been running "manual" water changes (clicking a button in my web app lol what a life changer) until I get water level sensors worked out for replacing evaporated fresh water and failsafe in the auto water change procedure.
One of these sensors will be submerged full-time and function as a low-level sensor. The other will be at the high-water line. And probably a backup set for both.
My Problem
I do not trust most float sensors based on magnetic reed switches. I have had several float valves/switches fail in the past year in fresh water and salt water. I cannot take the chance of crashing my tank or flooding my floors so I am attempting to emulate commercially-available products like this one with metal probes and additional backups. Theories on what that circuit looks like?
What I've Got So Far
I found this schematic online and I have a similar breadboard sample that seems to work:

My POC is actually simpler and uses one side of the probe wired to ground. The other side is connected to a GPIO input pin with an internal 50k pull-up on the Raspi. When submerged, the pin reads LOW. I'd love if it were that easy, but it seems too simple and I'm afraid of my limited skillset in this area.
Request for Feedback
It has been a long time since my ECE classes (am a professional software engineer) and I need some help validating the above circuit. Other forums have expressed concern that passing current through the salt water will corrode the probes quickly and leach elements.

Is this design "safe" or a "good idea"? (I will not hold you liable for opinions)

How much current will be passing through the water between the probes? If I measured correctly with a multimeter on my sample and the 50k pullup resistor on the Raspi, it is only 50 µA. Does that sound correct, and is that significant at all? Assuming no other shorts in the tank (faulty pumps are a risk I'm willing to take), will the current be localized to the few millimeters between the probes?

How concerned should I really be about corrosion and chemical reactions? My app can turn the pins on and sample for short durations over fairly long intervals (100ms samples every few hours). Will it really be a problem if the circuit is only active for a maximum of a few seconds per day? I plan on using marine-grade stainless cabling for the probes. Very small amounts of copper in the water can crash a tank.


Thanks in advance!


To reduce the corrosion issue, you should use an alternating current for the probe.  You can use an H bridge to create it, it doesn't need to be a sine wave.


I bet that is the secret behind the Red Sea probe I linked. Thanks!

I would look for capacitive proximity sensors to mount on the outside of the aquarium. Proven industrial solution for non-contact level detection. There is no problem with sticking contacts, no problem with leakage currents, electrolysis, corrosion etc.. Example: https://docs.rs-online.com/d25e/A700000010557664.pdf

@MrGerber - thanks for the idea! My immediate concern is that the "gunk" that builds up on the walls of the sump will remain wet and keep the sensor active well after the water level has fallen. But I suppose I could play around with the sensitivity to see how trustworthy it is.

Use a prism-type optical sensor. These are common in the aquarium hobby.
Example: https://www.saltwateraquarium.com/v2-fmm-optical-level-sensor-os-1-neptune-systems/
This avoids all the issues you list, while making no electrical connection at all to the tank water. Very safe.

I have considered this approach and may fall back on that. My concern (maybe not valid) is that these will be in my sump which can have lots of microbubbles from a skimmer and bright lights from a refugium that may interfere. I'm also afraid of one of them being knocked loose by accident without me realizing.
I'd also like to re-use a float valve mount in the sump which is internal. And its becoming a personal obsession of mine to figure out how Red Sea made theirs ;)

The way the prism works there should be no issue with ambient light. Some bubbles shouldn’t be an issue either, but you could use software to filter out ‘noise’ they might cause.

Thanks for the idea! I will consider this approach more seriously. I dismissed it initially because others like it are meant to be mounted on the outside of the glass and the glass in my sump gets dirty real fast. The one you linked seems like it may be able to be submerged so I'll take a closer look.

That's just one example. There's lots of choices, including complete auto top-off kits with sensor.

Yeah I dug into these a bit more and found a form factor that mounts from above and includes 4 different detection levels. I think I am going to give that a shot and add a float switch on top just for extra failsafe. I also intend to do some clever tricks with timers in software to detect if a sensor has failed. I can store the last 5 or so run durations and if the current runtime exceeds the max of those (with some margin), I'll shut everything down and send myself an email. Thanks for chatting!
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0D5XMGCLM/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A31G33MT63S07E&psc=1
